# User Defined Function in Pig Latin

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions, pig-udf

I am using Java to create a User Defined Function UDF for Pig Latin in a Hadoop environment. I want to create multiple output files. I have tried to create a Java program to output these CSV files as below:

```
public String exec(Tuple input) 
    throws IOException {

  if(input.equals("age")){
      outputFile = new FileWriter("C:\\UDF\\output_age.csv");
  }else{
      outputFile = new FileWriter("C:\\UDF\\output_general.csv");
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any alternative method to do that, whether by Java or by Pig Latin itself?

Comment: Where is it failing?

Comment: Simply the csv file is not created

Comment: Might I suggest please that the `udf` tag be edited? Personally I view UDF as being [Universal Disk Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) and not "user defined function". It can be quite confusing if you mix the two... Unfortunately I'm not sure how to edit/change the tags just yet

Comment: Does `c:\UDF` exist? Do you have permission to write to it?

Comment: yes it does. but the csv file is not. The problem when I edit the same java program, by adding the main method, it works fine. But when running java through Pig Latin it does not work.

Comment: @MohdZoubi just one thing; DO NOT use `FileWriter`. It does not allow you to specify the encoding with which the file should be written. If you are using Java 7+, use JSR 203 instead (`Paths.get()`, `Files.newBufferedWriter()`)

Comment: I will try it many thanks

Comment: The tuple argument will never equal the string "age". You have to extract elements from the tuple like it were a list. Also, if you are not running pig in local mode, then the file can't be written because the filesystem is HDFS, where there is no C drive

Comment: Trying to create multiple output files from within a Pig UDF is simply a very bad idea. Can you elaborate on what it is that you want to achive from a design point of view?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the UDFs, you need to take care of the data types. Here `exec` method takes tuple as input. To read tuple values, you need to use `tuple.get(0)` notation. i.e.

```
public String exec(Tuple input) 
    throws IOException {
  String inputAge = input.get(0).toString();
  if(inputAge.equals("age")){
      // file creation logic 
      outputFile = new FileWriter("C:\\UDF\\output_age.csv");
  }else{
      // file creation logic
      outputFile = new FileWriter("C:\\UDF\\output_general.csv");
  }
}
```

You can refer [Writing Java UDF in Pig](http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/02/writing-java-udf-in-apache-pig.html) for the reference.